# Migrating from Watcom Fortran to gfortran and do not understand this error

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to migrate working code from Watcom Fortran to gfortran. I have an open statement:

```
  OPEN (UNIT    = oufile,
 *      FILE    = OUPATH,
 *      ACTION  = 'WRITE',
 *      ACCESS  = 'SEQUENTIAL',
 *      STATUS  = 'UNKNOWN',
 *      CARRIAGECONTROL = 'YES',
 *      BLOCKSIZE = 80,
 *      FORM    = 'FORMATTED',
 *      IOSTAT  = OPERR,
 *      ERR     = 400)
```

Yes, that is F77 style. This thing is a dinosaur. The *'s are continuation characters. When I compile with gfortran and get this error:

```
      *      STATUS  = 'UNKNOWN',
                                1
Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)
.f(158,32): error : Syntax error in OPEN statement.
```

I am stumped on why it is barfing on the comma. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you require compatibility with any old data files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CARRIAGECONTROL is not a standard keyword for OPEN, neither is BLOCKSIZE. Remove both of those to begin with and see what you get. Then read the gfortran documentation to see if there are suitable replacements. BLOCKSIZE you can probably do without - I am not certain, offhand, how gfortran handles traditional Fortran carriage control (especially as that is a deleted feature.)

Comment: Recent gfortran added carriagecontrol support with compiler option -fdec

Comment: Both CARRIAGECONTROL and BLOCKSIZE are keywords recognized by DEC-heritage compilers (DEC/Compaq/Intel(, but ‘YES’ is not a value those compilers accept for CARRIAGECONTROL. Try CARRIAGECONTROL=‘FORTRAN’ with the option @tim18 mentioned. I should have noted that it wasn’t the comma that gfortran complained about but what followed it.

Comment: I definitely needed the CARRIAGECONTROL to work. Knowing the software that consumes the output file, I am certain that BLOCKSIZE is going to be an issue for some silly reason as well. Thanks, @tim18 for the compiler option.